# Drawing with transparency - performance issue

Tags: opencv

I am using this code to draw lines with transparency on some `cv::Mat` where **Alpha** is different for each line:

```
cv::Mat render(){
    for(size_t i=0;i<n;++i){
        auto trasparent_layer = canava.clone();
        cv::line(trasparent_layer, lines[i].p1, lines[i].p2, color, 10);
        const auto alpha = get_alpha(i); //Alpha is different for each line
        cv::addWeighted(trasparent_layer, alpha, canava, 1-alpha, 0, canava);
    }
    return canava;
}
```

With many lines, this approach is perfect for performance killing. What can I do to achieve better performance?

Comment: Using LineIterator and blend manually each pixel on the line? Seems faster

Comment: @Miki Thanks it is interesting. I did not know about it before. Trying..

Comment: you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36970804/5294258) example of using LineIterator

Comment: I have just implement and tried it.. LineIterator is very useful tool. However, I figured out lately that I need line with stroke width. not just 1 pixel width line :(

Comment: If the idea works, you can 1) use Bresenham algorithm for [thick lines](https://github.com/ArminJo/STMF3-Discovery-Demos/blob/master/lib/graphics/src/thickLine.cpp), or 2) for each of your points on LineIterator draw a circle of given radius...

Comment: @Miki thanks for your help.. I will try and benchmark